# How can I get http headers in WebBrowser?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I wrote a WP7 web browser app called ["Cute Browser"](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/apps/1ca4292a-36a1-4e1b-98ff-d1899003fee0).

There is a problem that when navigating to an unkown `content-type` page such as 'application/stream', the `WebBrowser` is always `navigating`.

After my many experiments, I found out a method to detect the `always navigating` status using invoke the script:

```
var readyStateChange = function(){ 
    if(document.readyState == 'interactive') { 
        document.detachEvent('onreadystatechange', readyStateChange);
        window.external.Notify('MaybeWml');
    } 
} 
if(document.readyState != 'complete'){
    document.attachEvent('onreadystatechange', readyStateChange); 
}
```

I want to know is any possible to get the `Http Headers` using `WebBrowser` without start another `HttpRequest`?